# Why is adding text causing error with player movement?

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

My code was working just fine until I added text for health and survivors saved.

Now the line controller.Move(moveVelocity); gives the error NullRefeenceexption because controller is null.

Strange thing is if I go into LivingEntity and comment out all the lines with

Health.text or SurvivorsSaved.text it works again.

Anyone know why?

Code:

```
public class Player : LivingEntity {

    public float moveSpeed = 5;

    Camera viewCamera;
    PlayerController controller;
    GunController gunController;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        controller = GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        gunController = GetComponent<GunController>();
        viewCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Movement input
        Vector3 moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        Vector3 moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * moveSpeed;
        controller.Move(moveVelocity);

        // Look input
        Ray ray = viewCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
        float rayDistance;

        if (groundPlane.Raycast(ray, out rayDistance))
        {
            Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(rayDistance);
            //Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin,point,Color.red);
            controller.LookAt(point);
        }

        // Weapon input
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            gunController.Shoot();
        }
    }

}

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class LivingEntity : MonoBehaviour, IDamageable
{

    public float startingHealth;
    protected float health;
    protected bool dead;
    private float playerhealth=100;
    private int Survivorssaved=0;

    public Text Health;
    public Text SurvivorsSaved;

    public event System.Action OnDeath;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        health = startingHealth;
        Health.text = "Health: " + playerhealth;
        SurvivorsSaved.text = "Survivors Saved:" + Survivorssaved;
    }

    public void TakeHit(float damage, RaycastHit hit)
    {
        TakeDamage(damage);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        if (GameObject.Equals(gameObject, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player")))
        {
            playerhealth = health;
            Health.text = "Health: " + playerhealth;
            SurvivorsSaved.text = "Survivors Saved: " + Survivorssaved;
        }
        if (health <= 0 && !dead)
        {
            if(GameObject.Equals(gameObject, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player")))
            {  
            }
            if (GameObject.Equals(gameObject, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Zombie")))
            {
                ScoreManager.Instance.AddScore(100);
            }
            if (GameObject.Equals(gameObject, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Survivor")))
            {
                ScoreManager.Instance.RemoveScore(500);
            }
            Die();
        }
    }

    public void HealDamage(float damage)
    {
        health += damage;
        playerhealth = health;
        Survivorssaved += 1;
        Health.text = "Health: " + playerhealth;
        SurvivorsSaved.text = "Survivors Saved: " + Survivorssaved;
    }

    protected void Die()
    {
        dead = true;
        if (OnDeath != null)
        {
            OnDeath();
        }
        GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into the idea of a [mcve], specifically minimal. It looks like the problem in this case might be as simple as the link (in the scene editor) from the `Player` to a `PlayerController` not being set.

Comment: So I went into the Unity and double checked everything and found the source of the problem. While I was giving the text object to the player survivors and zombies were also asking for it and I wasn't giving it to them. Unfortunately now I have a whole other problem because zombies aren't supposes to have that so I need to rething this living entity code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and I do not see were I mark it as resolved so I will simply post the solution.

While playerController was being passed to Player correctly when I went and checked in the unity Scene editor I found that the text objects for health and survivors rescued was being asked for by zombies and survivors as well and they were tying to pass information into the text despite not being passed the text objects.

I am still not passing it to the zombies or survivors but by changing the code around a bit I got it to work by making sure zombies and survivors were never passing any value into the text files.